# How to get the image of Dexterity content types and show in a batched listing view?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I need to create a batched listing view of a folder with Dexterity-based content types (Plone 4.2), that also shows their image.
I found two ways of getting the image of the objects.

Method 1:

in the template (inside the batch)

```
         ...
         <div tal:define="item_object item/getObject;">
              <img tal:condition="exists:item_object/@@images/image1"
                   tal:replace="structure item_object/@@images/image1/mini" />
         </div>
```

Method 2:

in the view class

```
def get_item_image(self, item):
    itemobj = item.getObject()
    scales = getMultiAdapter((itemobj, self.request), name='images')
    scale = scales.scale('image1', scale='mini')
    imageTag = None
    if scale is not None:
       imageTag = scale.tag()
    return imageTag
```

and in the template

```
         ...
         <div tal:define="item_image python:view.get_item_image(item)">
              <img tal:condition="item_image"
                   tal:replace="structure item_image" />
         </div>
```

Can anyone advise me which way is the best (if any) as to not wake up objects?

Answer (score 2):

I think the current `plone.app.imaging` needs to wake up the object in any case to access its image scales (they are stored inside the object, after all). So it is not very easy to generate an wake-up free listing of the objects.

The good news is that Dexterity content types are more lightweight than Archetypes content types and doing raw listing by iterating over `folder.contentItems()` in your template should not be that expensive. In fact, it might even faster than through catalog query. So don't worry about waking up objects and just use `plone.app.imaging` method:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.imaging

Answer (score 1):

You effectively have to wakeup the object and get the field from the schema object.

```
<tal:def tal:define="item_object python:item.getObject()">
    <tal:if tal:condition="python:hasattr(item_object, 'Schema')">
        <tal:d2 tal:define="image python:item_object.Schema().getField('image');
                        image python:image and image.getAccessor(item_object)();"
            tal:condition="image">
            <img id="image-rubrique" alt="" tal:attributes="src string:${item_object/absolute_url}/image_mini" />
        </tal:d2>
    </tal:if>
</tal:def>
```